# Unable to configure port mapping for Azure availability set in the new portal

Tags: azure, availability

Where is the option to configure port mappings in the new Microsoft Azure portal (http://portal.azure.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're setting up a Classic Virtual Machine (that is, with the legacy APIs, available in both the new and old portals), you'll find the settings under Endpoints, when you look at your VM's settings:

[image: classic endpoints]

If you created a VM using the new Resource Manager (either via portal or via ARM script), the concept of Endpoint no longer exists. Instead, you have an IP address, associated with a NIC. And that NIC is inside a Network Security Group (NSG). In the NSG, you define inbound and outbound port rules. A few more clicks away, but...

First look at your VM's settings and navigate to the network interface:

[image: NIC]

Then navigate to the network security group:

[image: Network Security Group]

Finally, edit the inbound rules:

[image: inbound rules]

Note: You may also add outbound rules.

Comment: Just to complete your solution: if you need to do a port translation (i.e. different port on the public side than on the VM itself) for an ARM VM, you'll need to put the VM behind a load balancer and use Inbound NAT Rules for the port translation.