# Azure: How to reach my Ubuntu server in the Browser?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, continuous-integration

I have created an Ubuntu server on Azure and installed GoCD, a continuous delivery software, on it via PuTTY.

Usually, when GoCD is installed locally, it can be reached via http://localhost:8153/go (similiar to if you install Apache Tomcat).

But what must I type in the URL bar in order to reach my Go installation on my Azure Ubuntu server?

Comment: Have you opened port 8153 to the outside world yet? If not, you need to do so. I show how in [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/737796/99269) to another question, for both Classic- and ResourceManager-based VMs.

Answer (score 1):

**You should open port 8153 in Azure NSG (Inbound rule)**. The port is not open by default.
[image]

More information about NSG please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-associations).

Comment: For apache, you need open port 80

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the public IP address of the server in place of localhost?

Example: http://0.0.0.0:8153/go

If that doesn't work there may be many things causing it, let me list a few..

1. The port may not be port forwarded for public use on the machine.
2. The software may not be working correctly, maybe some missing components?

Note: If the server is running in a virtual machine or on another computer in the house, and you haven't forwarded the port for azure, you should try using the local IP of the machine (or virtual machine) in place of localhost instead. Example: http://192.168.1.8:8153/go